# Can't print name by foreign key

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

Spring boot 2.5

Controller:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class OrdersController {
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(OrdersController.class);

    @GetMapping("/orders")
    public String getAllOrders(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("ordersList", orderRepository.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("appName", appName);
        return "orders";
    }
```

orders.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${appName}">Order template title</title>
    <link th:href="@{/public/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container entity_list">
    <h2>Orders</h2>
    <br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="left" th:text="'Total count: ' + ${ordersList.size()}"/>
            <td colspan="3" align="right"><a th:href="@{/order/add}">Add</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="50">ID</th>
            <th width="120">Name</th>
            <th width="200">Created At</th>
            <th width="200">Updated At</th>
            <th width="200">Category</th>
            <th width="60"></th>
            <th width="60"></th>
        </tr>
        <th:block th:each="order : ${ordersList}">
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${{order.id}}"/>
                <td><a th:href="@{/order/view/{id}(id=${order.id})}"/><span th:text="${order.name}"/></td>
                <td th:text="${{order.created}}"/>
                <td th:text="${{order.updated}}"/>
                <td th:text="${{order.category}}"/>
                <td><a th:href="@{/order/edit/{id}(id=${order.id})}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a th:href="@{/order/delete/{id}(id=${order.id})}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

jpa:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Orders, Integer> {

    // Spring Data - use JPQL -> generate SQL query on runtime
    public List<Orders> findByName(String name);

    public List<Orders> findByNameOrderById(String name);
}
```

Models:

```
@Entity
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date created;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date updated;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;



@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date created;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date updated;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "category")
    private Orders orders;
```

And here result:

As you can see print category's id. But I need to print category's name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change tour orders.html and in order.category edit like below:

```
            <td th:text="${{order.category?.name}}"/>
```

Hope useful

Comment: Get runtime error: Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "order.category.name" (template: "orders" - line 32, col 21).Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null

Comment: only this help me:  <td th:text="${{order.category?.name}}"/>